# zf2 ServiceNotFoundException, how to fix it

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using zend frame work and I created a model inside my module src folder in side Model folder , I want to use that model as service and i invoked that model class in Module.php configuration but when I run the application it shows me the Error ServiceNotFoundException. 

`Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::createFromInvokable: failed retrieving "authdbservice(alias: AuthDbService)" via invokable class "Authentication\Model\AuthDb"; class does not exist`

here is my module.php file
    class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface,

```
ConfigProviderInterface, ServiceProviderInterface
    {
        /**
         * 
         * {@inheritDoc}
         * @see \Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface::getAutoloaderConfig()
         */
        public function getAutoloaderConfig() 
        {
            return array(
                 'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                     __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
                 ),
                 'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                     'namespaces' => array(
                         __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                     ),
                 ),
             );
        }
        /**
         * 
         * {@inheritDoc}
         * @see \Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface::getConfig()
         */
        public function getConfig()
        {
            return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
        }
        /**
         * 
         * {@inheritDoc}
         * @see \Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ServiceProviderInterface::getServiceConfig()
         */
        public function getServiceConfig()
        {
            return array(
                'invokables' => array(
                    'AuthService' => 'Authentication\Service\AuthService',
                    'AuthDbService' => 'Authentication\DbService\AuthDb',
                ),
            );
        }
    }
```

and here is my authDb Class

```
namespace Authentication\DbService;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Authentication\Entity\User;
use Authentication\Form\RegisterForm;
class AuthDb {

   protected $em;

   protected function getEntityManger() {
       if (null === $this->em) {
            $this->em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
        }
        return $this->em;
   }

   public function submitNewUser() {
       $form = new RegisterForm();
       $form->get('submit')->setValue('Register');
       $request = $this->getRequest();
       if ($request->isPost()) {
           $user = new User();
           $form->setInputFilter($user->getInputFilter());
           $form->setData($request->getPost());
           if ($form->isValid()) {
               $user->exchangeArray($form->getData());
               $user->__set('password', md5($user->__get('password')));
               $this->getEntityManager()->persist($user);
               $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
               return $this->redirect()->toRoute('auth', array('action' => 'login'));
           } else {
               return array('form' => $form, 'messages' => $form->getMessages());
           }
       }
   }

}
```

my directories and files structure is

```
./Authentication
./Authentication/autoload_classmap.php
./Authentication/Module.php
./Authentication/view
./Authentication/view/authentication
./Authentication/view/authentication/auth
./Authentication/view/authentication/auth/register.phtml
./Authentication/view/authentication/auth/login.phtml
./Authentication/config
./Authentication/config/module.config.php
./Authentication/src
./Authentication/src/Authentication
./Authentication/src/Authentication/Service
./Authentication/src/Authentication/Service/AuthService.php
./Authentication/src/Authentication/Controller
./Authentication/src/Authentication/Controller/AuthController.php
./Authentication/src/Authentication/Model
./Authentication/src/Authentication/Model/AuthDbService.php
./Authentication/src/Authentication/Entity
./Authentication/src/Authentication/Entity/User.php
./Authentication/src/Authentication/Form
./Authentication/src/Authentication/Form/LoginForm.php
./Authentication/src/Authentication/Form/RegisterForm.php
```

I think there is miss understood in configuration for me in this case
any idea to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, i have to admit that it was very complex to me, but now it's a little bit more easier,
as i wanted my database model as service accessible in my controllers and the other services i have to made some small changes by using some large aspect of design patterns(factory in this case).
so i put the AuthDbService.php file inside Model folder, but it hasn't correct name space, so I had to change the namespace to

`namespace Authentication\Model` (this is the coorect namespace)

I also changed the class name from `AuthDb` to `AuthDbService`

and after that i was able to use this inside my other controller.
I changed my `getServiceConfig` function to

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'AuthService' => 'Authentication\Service\AuthService',
            'AuthDbService' => 'Authentication\Model\AuthDbService',
        )
    );
}
```

so now i can use it inside my controller, bu here is the thing!
i want to use another service(`AuthService`) inside `AuthDbService` and here is the new issue. because I cant use `AuthService` inside my `AuthDbService`.

why? `AuthService` is a service which is accessible only from Zend ServiceManager and for doing this i need to have access to the ServiceManager inside AuthDbService class, as far as it's a Model not Controller and it's not extending from `AbstractActionController` technically i don't have access to ServiceManager to inject `AuthService`.

so i have to inject ServiceManager first in my ServiceModel(`AuthDbService`) and for doing this i had to make some changes again inside my Module.php `getServiceConfig` function again.

but before that I added these lines of codes inside my `AuthDbService` class

```
protected $serviceLocator;

    /**
     * serviceLocator Setter
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     * @author Ehsan Aghaei
     */
    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) 
    {
       $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    /**
     * serviceLocator Getter
     * @return \Authentication\Model\Service\unknown
     * @author Ehsan Aghaei
     */
    protected function getServiceLocator() 
    {
       return $this->serviceLocator;
    }
```

I just made setter and getter to Inject the ServiceManger Object inside this class.
after that, I made my changes to the `getServiceConfig` as the following

```
public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'invokables' => array(
                'AuthService' => 'Authentication\Service\AuthService',
            ),
            'factories' => array(
                'AuthDbService' => function ($sm) {
                    $authService = new AuthDbService();
                    $authService->setServiceLocator($sm);
                    return $authService;
                }
            ),
        );
    }
```

now i have access to the service Manager and from the Service Manager i can access to another services.
and that was the way I fixed my problem.
I hope it help someone like me. ;)